# Unable to delete boot entries using efibootmgr

Tags: boot, uefi

This used to work in the past but since recently deleting entries with
`efibootmgr` fails with return value 15. Changing the boot order fails as
well. However, creating new entries does succeed, surprisingly. So it doesn't
seem to be a write permission issue.

Display the last boot entry:

```
% sudo efibootmgr | tail -1
Boot0023* Debian, kernel 4.0.0-1
```

Trying to delete this entry fails:

```
% sudo efibootmgr -b 0023 -B; echo $?
efibootmgr: Boot entry 0023 not found
efibootmgr: Could not delete boot variable: Success
15
```

I couldn't find a corresponding bug report or anything related to this issue.
So it's probably not a common problem.

What could be the issue here and how to fix it?

System:
Debian stretch/sid, kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64, efibootmgr version 0.11.0

Answer (score -1):

Try it without the leading `00`, as in `sudo efibootmgr -B -b 23`.  Might work.